# Firebase Firestore Easy to remember references

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are using Firebase Firestore for data storage. When a user creates a new room, we want the reference to be easy to remember so that a user can share the room ID/code with other users.

At present Firestore will create a unique reference such as:
DvfTMYED5cWdo5qIraZg

This is too long and difficult to remember or share. We could set a different reference manually, but they have to be unique. The other point is that users can create multiple rooms so the reference would have to change each time.

Is there a way to use shorter/better references for this use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase/Firestore has nothing built in for shorter references, as they wouldn't have enough entropy to statistically guarantee uniqueness. But since creating chat rooms is likely a fairly low-volume operation, you can implement this in your app by:

1. Generating your own token for each room, for example a counter.
2. Checking in the database whether this room is available.
3. If the token is already taken, generate another one and try again.

This is pretty much how auto-increment fields work on most databases. On Firestore you'd create a document where you keep the current counter value:

```
chat_rooms (collection)
  COUNTERS: { last_room_id: 2 } (document)
  chatroom_1: { room_id: 1, name: "Chat room for Stuart and Frank" } (document)
  chatroom_2: { room_id: 2, name: "Public chat room" } (document)
```

When you now create a new room, you:

1. Start a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).
2. Read `COUNTERS`.
3. Read the `last_room_id`, and increment it.
4. Write the updated document back.
5. Create a new document for the new chat room.
6. Commit the transaction

Note that there are many ways to generate the codes. The counter approach above is a simple one, but I recommend checking out more options. Some interesting reading:

- [How to generate unique coupon codes?](https://www.voucherify.io/blog/how-to-generate-unique-coupon-codes)
- [Generating human-readable/usable, short but unique IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543715/generating-human-readable-usable-short-but-unique-ids)
- [Unique Identifiers that are User-Friendly and Hard to Guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421463/unique-identifiers-that-are-user-friendly-and-hard-to-guess)

Comment: Thanks @Frank, Good to know. I guess the other alternative is have the user manually enter a roomname and keep that as the doc ID.

Comment: Definitely. But you'd need a roundtrip there too to check if the name they entered is still available. That's why the default IDs are so "chaotic": they are generated in the clients and are statistically guaranteed to be unique, which means that they can also work while the client is offline.